# How to get AT Command Response?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, at-command, ussd

I am developing a SIM Toolkit application using C#. I use the following code to get the response. But it shows me unformatted text which is not readable. This USSD code should display "Your Current balance is 100.00".

```
 private void cmdcode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cmd = "AT";
        _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM7", 115200);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        _serialPort.Open();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        _serialPort.WriteLine(cmd + "CUSD=1,"+"*566#");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        string value = _serialPort.ReadExisting();            
            MessageBox.Show(value);
            _serialPort.Close();
    }
```

And another problem is when I click 1st time it displays the unformatted text but when click again that button it show the null message.

Comment: The baudrate looks like a guess, don't ignore the parity, stopbits, stopbits and handshake settings.  You should get "ERROR" back.  The command requires double-quotes so it should be something like "AT+CUSD=1,\"*556#\"" in your code.

Comment: I use this setting 
_serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
            _serialPort.DtrEnable = true;

But i didn't received any thing in my message box.

Comment: You specify a baud of 115200 in the code snippet, and 9600 in your comment. Which is correct? How do you know the DataBits, Parity etc are correct?